# crash from aar-library neither showing in Developer console nor HockeyApp after publishing

Tags: android, native, crash-reports, aar, hockeyapp

in our App we're using a native library packaged as an .aar and HockeyApp for error reporting. The .aar-code draws information on a SurfaceFragment, the rest of the Application uses standard Android libraries.

After publishing the app to Google Play, users have experienced crashes of the .aar-library, after which the SurfaceFragment stays blank, the surrounding app doesn't crash. During development, these reports were sent to HockeyApp. 
Now that the app is published, the dialog for crash reports isn't HockeyApp's any more, but a standard google one. However, the reports neither show up in the developer console nor in HockeyApp.

How/where can I get the error reports for the native library?